# 403 error with mechanicalsoup

Tags: http-status-code-403, mechanicalsoup

Why do I get 403 when I try to scrape hacked.com and how can I get around it?
According to doesitusecloudflare.com, there is no cloudflare in the way (http://www.doesitusecloudflare.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhacked.com%2Fwp-login.php)
the robots.txt allow any useragent and only disallow access to the wp-admin log in.

```
>>> import mechanicalsoup
>>> browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
>>> browser.get('https://google.com')
<Response [200]>
>>> browser.get('https://hacked.com')
<Response [403]>
>>> browser.get('https://hacked.com').content
b'<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can see in [mechanicalsoup/browser.py#L106](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup/blob/7171e2b79ba0fbe02a7245066cb5536ddb2fe94e/mechanicalsoup/browser.py#L106), `.get()` is just a wrapper around `requests.get()`, so let's drop to that instead.

As we can see; the problem persists with just requests:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://hacked.com')
>>> response
<Response [403]>
>>>
```

I had an inkling, so I removed the `User-Agent` string:

```
>>> request = response.request
>>> request.headers
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', ...}
>>> del(request.headers['User-Agent'])
>>> request.headers
{...}
>>>
```

And tried again:

```
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> session.send(request)
<Response [200]>
>>>
```

Tada!  It looks like this is someone over at [hacked](https://hacked.com)'s attempt to avoid a certain bot - even though their `robots.txt` says you're allowed.

So, back to the problem in your context, it seems like we just need to set a `User-Agent` string that isn't what `requests` sends by default.  I can't see a way to *unset* it with MechanicalSoup, so here's the best method I found:

```
>>> import mechanicalsoup
>>> b = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
>>> b.set_user_agent('my-awesome-script')
>>> b.get('https://hacked.com')
<Response [200]>
>>>
```